# AS3 Component Parameters enable/disable based on another parameter value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-component

Is it possible to hide/show or enable/disable component parameters based on the value of another parameter? Example:

"showTextField"
checked would show formatting parameters (or allow them to be changed)

unchecked would hide formatting parameters(or disallow them to be changed - greyed out)

Comment: Flex SDK offers bindable objects

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flex you can take advantage of [Data Binding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cc0.html)

This will allow you to bind properties of one object to another.

This can also dispatch a [PropertyChangeEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/PropertyChangeEvent.html) when a value in your object is changed.

If you're working with a pure AS3 project you may want to check out this 3rd party library

http://nanosome.org/notify/